# How do I know which functional interface is associated with the method?

Tags: java, function, java-stream

`map()` is associated with the `Function` interface. And how can I know which interfaces other methods are associated with, for example `findFirst()`?

Comment: What does `findFirst` have to do with functional interfaces? It is just a method of `Stream`.

Comment: I guess you mean the `Function` interface. You know what findFirst, and all the other Java methods in the world expect by simply reading their javadoc: map expects a Function (see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-), whereas findFirst() doesn't take any argument (see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findFirst--)

Comment: @JBNizet Yes, I was wrong, thanks. This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> map() is associated with the Functional interface

*No, it is not*. For the presence of tag java-stream, it's just another [API from the class `Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map(java.util.function.Function)) which has the following syntax :

```
<R> Stream<R> map(Function<? super T,​? extends R> mapper)
```

Yes, the argument used within i.e. `Function` is a `FunctionalInterface`. You can find similar `FunctionalInterface`s within the [`java.util.function`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/package-summary.html) package of the `java.base` module (Java-9 above) of the JDK.

Comment: Yes, thx. I thought that findFirst() is connected to the Supplier interface, like a map() with a Function